# CSS/div positioning that does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, positioning

I have been searching for an answer for a good hour without luck so It may be OK to ask my silly question:

I am trying to overlay a legend over a map. The map is generated with openlayers and lives in a `div` called map. the legend is an html table but could be a picture as well and lives in another `div` called legend.

hence the HTML

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
</body>
```

and the CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    }
html, body {
    background-color: red;
    }
#map{
    position:relative;
}
#legend{
  position:absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 100px;
}
```

This works just fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but not in IE8.

In IE8 the legend is shown in its place, the red page background is behind but the map div has disappeared. Note that IE still loads the map tiles etc but seems to be putting them either behind the background or somewhere not on the screen...

If you have any suggestions, greatly appreciated!

Comment: please create a jsfiddle of this, it will make more sense

Comment: Put both div#map and div#legend inside a div#container. Give the div#container a style of position: relative and give div#legend a style of position: absolute; top: 1%; left: 100px; Use Z-Index for "layering" the elements - Advises = Use shorthand property such as margin: 0; instaed of margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; - Use a generic font family name at the end in the font-family: Arial; - http://jsfiddle.net/dq9uD/

Answer (score 0):

Without the whole HTML page, it can be hard to give you a correct answer, to know what's exactly going on. Though you can use conditional IE tags to make your design work in Internet Explorer. [More information here.](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html)

You will find that most IE8 quirks can be fixed by changing the positioning by a few pixels, position type, the `display:` value, or making elements at `display:none;`.

Firebug is your friend.